# Should I encrypt files saved by my program

Tags: data, file-handling, files, formatting, interoperability

I'm trying to decide on what format I should save data in, and hopefully this question will help me come to a decision. The program I'm writing uses 'databases' in which `word=meaning` (not a dictionary, that was just an example). I don't really want people to be able to manually edit these 'databases' without my program easily, but at the same time I'm looking for interoperability between programming langauges (namely C#, PHP, Java and Objective C)

At the minute, the main contenders are SQLite, XML and SQL Server CE (although PHP doesn't have support for Server CE, but that doesn't have to be too much of an issue). Really, my question is, should I use encryption because I have read that it is often just as easy to decrypt? And if you support encryption, how do you deal with the encryption key - do I just generate a long, complicated string?

Or is binary enough? Nothing in the database is too critical, however I would like to have an `isEditable` 'key' so my program knows whether to allow edits or not. And I'd also like to use my own file extension.

Comment: Does it add business value to spend time implementing this data hiding?

Comment: @Daenyth That's a good point. I suppose it does because my program is a niche so if the data is freely available, other programs could be written to use it, which is something I don't really want to be honest.

Comment: @Andy - Why do you want it to be interoperable, then?  Are you planning on coding things to access it in all those?

Comment: @Bobson To put it simply, yes. Perhaps not in the short term, but I don't want to have to keep changing file formats in the future when I release programs in those languages.

Comment: @Andy: My gut says YAGNI. How much time have you spent creating your tool for this data? Do you think someone else will really spend that much time reverse engineering it?

Comment: I suggest reading [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12854077/best-encode-decode-for-binary-file-in-java-and-c-sharp) and it's answers, especially the comments on the second one.

Comment: @Bobson So, are you suggesting that I just write everything to a file in binary? I guess that could work, although it would mean more code to read and process the file. Though, if I'm just going to be using binary, SQLite would be suitable then.

Comment: And @Daenyth, perhaps you may have another point. I'm just thinking of the future, and if my application gets bigger I might need it. Though that starts a second 'debate': is a bad thing having other software use your file format - Microsoft allow it?

Comment: @Andy: You "might" need it, which logically implies that you 1) currently don't need it and 2) might NOT need it in the future, meaning that this is wasted work.

Comment: @Andy, it is defintely worth thinking about _why_ you don't want other people being able to use your data. If your reason is simply that you want them to use your tool, you might actually detract from that possibility by minimizing the interoperability of your application. A lot of applications become popular because the use of an open data format (or an API, either works in this case) that makes their functionality easy to extend and build off of.

Comment: @DanAlbert On reflection, I suppose the reasons for allowing people to view the file easy outweigh the reasons why I might want to stop people from using the data. Thinking about it, using an open data format might help enrich the software instead of driving people away from it, due to nature of the software. Thanks for your comment

Comment: Another win for open software :)

Comment: @DanAlbert I think so! :) Now I've just got to decide between SQLite and XML - any opinions?

Comment: @Andy It really depends on the nature of your data. If you have a rigidly defined structure that you won't be straying from, SQLite is the way to go. If you need something that will be more flexible with future changes, XML might be better. If the latter, I'm a big proponent of [JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) over XML. It often has much simpler language bindings (it's trivial in Python, JS, PHP, etc.). If you want the flexibility _and_ the database model, then you're looking for a [key-value store](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoSQL#Key.E2.80.93value_stores).

Comment: @DanAlbert Sorry for the slow reply. With regards to the structure, the 'database' at the minute will only actually contain entries with two values so I'm not sure if SQLite would be overkill (plus do you know if I can use it in C# for commercial use?). I also like JSON, but again I'm not sure about the legal constraints when using it with C# because it is not natively supported in .NET.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9801/discussion-between-dan-albert-and-andy)

Answer (score 6):

I'd say no, you should not encode them for multiple reasons

- Having them more open is less work for you. Does your business *need* to spend the extra work hiding it?
- Having it encrypted creates lock-in. Lock-in is not a selling feature
- If your app decrypts it, that means that the encryption can be cracked by examining your app, so you've just done work for little gain - as soon as one person cracks it, anyone can repeat it.
- Having it open empowers your users to do things with the data you did not foresee and did not add to your app - this means that you've given them extra utility.
- Open data will make future partnerships easier because a partner will not need to write handing logic.
- Open data does not mean that competing tools using that data will magically appear - competitors still need to write their own software, which is likely not as good a proposition as just using yours - how much effort will someone want to go to just to NOT use your software?

This is by no means a complete list, just what's off the top of my head.

Comment: You raise a lot of valid points here and they help make my decision a bit easier. Not implementing encryption is most likely in the best interest of me, as well as the programs users, because it allows for greater flexibility and I do suppose there's any great reason for the 'database' to be encrypted on reflection. The question still remains though, SQLite or XML - what do you think?

Comment: @Andy: That's a different question than this one and will be dictated by how you use, store, and transport your data.

Comment: I cannot upvote this answer enough.  Especially point #2, lock-in.  I'll add one additional item - files get corrupted.  It doesnt happen often, but if you have a large user base *someone* will have the problem.  Non-encrypted files are then easier to recover.

Answer (score 5):

One really important fact that people always overlook about encryption is that it does absolutely nothing to ensure the integrity of your data. Encryption solves the problem of confidentiality; it prevents unauthorized users from reading the data. Encryption will make it harder for someone to modify the data in a useful way, but it isn't solving the right problem.

If you're worried about other programs changing your data, what you actually need is a trusted fingerprint of your data. A common way to do this is to generate a hash of the database when your program modifies it and then sign that hash with a private key. When you load the database, compute the hash, compare it to the signed hash, and verify that the signature is valid.

Now that the matter of theory is out of the way, it is worth noting that, in practice, encrypting your data might well be good enough for this kind of thing. Any blind modifications to encrypted structured data will likely corrupt the database, so that will prevent users from modifying the database using anything other than your application. If you also want to make sure no one else can *read* your data (it wasn't clear in the question), then you're probably safe to leave it at encryption and be done with it.

Comment: This decision has got really hard now because I've got two somewhat conflicting answers. As you said, encryption could still be a good option. However, that brings in the question of what I do with the encryption key (i.e how is it generated) and also what method I use, which is likely to make the program a lot more complicated, and it could put users off using the application. I suppose as well, if I don't add encryption now I'll still have the option for future versions of my program to support encrypted databases as well.

Comment: @Andy Encryption is hard. It's much harder when the encryption needs to be done from a user's machine and not your server. Including the key used for encryption leaves it vulnerable. Even if you scramble the key and reassemble it at run time, tools like [passe-partout](https://github.com/kholia/passe-partout) can still extract them from the program's memory. There is an entire industry dedicated to making this work (it's called DRM), and it's far from perfect. Is your application something that can be made into a web app? This problem is much easier solved if decryption happens on your server.

Comment: I can see that encryption is hard now, and unfortunately it would have to be done offline, as this is one of the key features of the software - the ability to work without an internet connection. So I think, as people have been saying, implementing encryption would be a lot of work for not much gain (if any).

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to limit tampering or limit the view of the data?  The potential solution for each would require slightly different implementations.

Tampering you would use hashes.  As a real world example, one application I worked on we would compute the hashes of strings and/or files.  When users downloaded the file, we checked the hash.  When user opened the file, we checked the hash.  This is because our client didn't want end users tampering with the files (jpg, etc.)  This prevented users from tampering with the file, because if they did, the hashes didn't match and they got an error.  Any file/string can be hashed, and if your don't want user tampering with strings or files without issue, store a hash of that data along with the string/file.  Passwords do not need to be encrypted, the solution would be to salt the password and then hash it.  Then the data store and application has no knowledge of user passwords.

Encryption would be used to hide information such as credit card and/or personal data.  Legal and regulatory requirements should define what needs to be encrypted.  If the application is storing sensitive data, then one fo the ways to prevent access is via encryption.  You can also limit access by defining ACLs etc.  but if you only want your user(s) to view the data, then encryption is your best option.

Also, only implement if required.  Going back to the example above, originally we did have any tamper resistence in the application.  Users downloaded files and opened and viewed locally.  Only after we had a requirement from a customer that users couldn't tamper with files then we implemented a hashing check.  When in design we considered two options, limiting access on the file system to the files that were downloaded, or using a hash.  We choose a hash because we were already calculating it on upload so it was relatively easy to add a check before the user could view it.

Comment: `Passwords do not need to be encrypted, store a password hash and then compute the hash of what the user typed and compare if valid.` rather, select a non-optimized function such as bcrypt or scrypt, *salt* the password and then hash it.

Comment: In the ideal world, I'd like to limit both tampering and viewing the data but I know realise in the real world, it probably isn't worth the effort. Hashing would be good, but the file will change and be updated online so I don't think this would work. When I update the file, I could also download the new hash I suppose but then you have the problem of keeping that safe. With regards to encryption, there will be no sensitive information stored - I was only inquiring because I wanted users to use my software to manage the files, but now I see that encryption may be too hard to implement

Comment: @Andy - If users are allowed to update the file, you could implement versioning.  Updates would be a new file being uploaded with a new hash.  But you are correct, the hash would have to updated.  Also computing hashes on files does take some time.  For small files not an issue, but if you have very large files it will take a second or two.

Comment: @Rath - Good point, I was too brief in my original answer, I will update.  Thx.

Comment: @JonRaynor As I say, the only problem with updated the hash is that it would have to be stored somewhere, and depending on where it's stored and how the hash is created it could be easy just to change it. The question is, is it better to deter users using a method that could so easily be hacked, or just leave it open anyway and not bother deterring users.

Comment: @Andy - True, we stored the file as a blob and hash in a server and local database which were synced periodically.  Users would have to get the ID and Password to the database to be able change the hash on records in the DB (which only a few developers and/or system admins knew), but if a System Admin logged in and started altering hashes on that table, that would be a problem.  The deterrent was there and the client was happy with the solution as the end users who tampered were immediately exposed.

Comment: @JonRaynor Thanks for that. Hashing does sound really good and useful, but unfortunately I don't think it is really applicable in my situation. +1 anyway! I think I'm just going to use some form of encoding or compression to obfuscate the code, to add that deterrent but also keep the interoperability and openness.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand your question, you don't really care if someone modifies or looks at your database, it's just you'd rather they didn't.

[Daenyth](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/205849/83924) makes a good argument why you *shouldn't* do that but if you decide to go with it anyway, consider a few things:

- Crypto is hard to get right

Even if you do encrypt your data with AES or what have you, the value of the data doesn't really call for encryption/protection. It may also make it harder to read the data in the future in a different language or even with a different library.

- You are better off with obfuscation

which means a simple Base64 will do. Of course that will do nothing to verify the integrity of the data as [Dan](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/205850/83924) noted but implementing signatures is still too costly. As an alternative, you might add padding to your file to conform with a set of fixed checksums (for some checksum function). Much lighter than signatures but still quite expensive.

If in the future you need to have a trusted connection to a remote database, [ask again](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/) when you implement it.

As for SQLite vs XML there is a question on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77726/xml-or-sqlite-when-to-drop-xml-for-a-database) on the same topic. Although closed it has some excellent answers.

---

Edit: If you are using Java you might want to consider zipping the file. You get both an illegible binary blob *and* a [checksum](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/zip/class-use/Checksum.html). I'm sure C# also has a version of this but I'm not familiar with that language.

Comment: I think you understand correctly; I'm not all too sure myself but I've come to conclusion it's not the end of the world if someone see's or modifies my database without my software and it wouldn't be worth the effort to try and stop them. However, Base64 does sound like a good option. If I used it, would I just write to the file in any old format or could I use XML in Base64 if you know what I mean?

Comment: Base64 doesn't care about the underlying format of the data; you can save your XML data in a buffer, pass it through Base64 and dump it in the file. To read, do the reverse. Of course you can't use Base64 with SQLite because (if I'm not mistaken) SQLite uses its own procedures to read/write to a file (true for PHP anyway). You could get around this somehow but it's not worth the effort.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This does sound like a good solution to be because nearly all programming languages support Base64 and it will still enable other programs to access the content if needed, it will just deter casual users from manually modifying things. I'm not sure if I need SQLite anyway, because to me it looks like overkill and I can't see that there will be much difference in performance with files less than 1 MB. Can you see any advantages of using SQLite over XML?

Comment: Not for the scale of 100-200 values. Look at the question on SO I've linked in my answer, it has good answers to help you in your decision. Another plus is XML can be transfered as-is through the network even with a text-based protocol, ie. a RESTful architecture.

Comment: Well, I'll have a lot more values than that, but looking at the question you linked to it's more about  the size of the file rather than the amount of values. According to the question, it seems that for my purposes XML should be fine but I'll do a little bit more digging.

Answer (score 1):

If all you're looking for is to discourage external editing, while providing for interoperability among different implementation languages, consider simply compressing the file.  It'll look like line noise if opened in a text editor, but if you use a standard compression algorithm you should be able to find (or write) a file compression library for most popular languages.  You even get the benefit of saving storage space, if your data sets get large.

Comment: +1 Wow, what a neat idea. Would you recommend a format to compress inperticular?

Comment: LZ (Lempel-Ziv) compression is pretty widely used, so you should stand a good change of finding implementations in most languages.  If you want to write it yourself, basic Huffman coding is pretty straightforward.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, however I meant which type of file would you recommend I compress (i.e XML, JSON, etc.)?

Comment: Also, it may sound like a strange question, but which is likely to be faster, encoding or compression?

Comment: Encoding is definitely faster, except if LZ doesn't want to create a dictionary first. The difference is going to be microseconds anyway. Now for the size... XML is likely to have a higher compression ratio (lots of repeated phrases) but is also likely to lead to a larger file (by a very small margin but larger nonetheless). That's just an estimate, you should run your own tests @Andy

Comment: @rath thank you for that. With regards to file size, when you say a 'larger file' - larger than what?

Comment: `size(lz(xml(data)))>=size(lz(json(data)))` @Andy

Comment: @rath :) I understand now